# Cannot create http connection with webhook in Airflow 2.0

Tags: airflow, webhooks, google-cloud-composer, httpconnection

We had a web hooks operator in Airflow 1.10.5 which was working perfectly fine. When we started migrating to airflow 2.1.0, We are not able to create the connection. We usually give Conn ID, Conn type as HTTP and Host and schema as https.

But, when I tried to add that, getting an error `General Error <class 'sqlalchemy.exc.DataError'>`

Tried searching, but no luck. Anyone who faced the same issue and resolved it?

Comment: You need to provide more details. Maybe also take a look at the documentation to see if you have the right parameters ? there were quite a number of changes since 1.10.5 (it's really, really old version) so things might have changed in 1.10.* already

Comment: What composer version are you using?